# .net 4.62 c# reference always points to GAC even installing nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget-package-restore

trying to add NuGet package System.Reflection 4.3.0 but the reference always point the GAC.

Other project is the same solution points to the correct path but only this project points to GAC.

I want the reference to having a path pointing to my package folder inside my project.

Comment: References in projects should *never* point at the GAC. It's meant for use at *runtime*, not *compile time*.

Comment: thats what question is for. for some reason it always point to GAC